# Problem with generics

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following statements :

```
    List<List<String>> myList  = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    List<ArrayList<String>> myList  = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

The first one gives compile error. Shouldn't we code to interface? Here I am forced to code by class not the interface. Is this a generics failure, or I am understanding it wrong?

Comment: It's meant to be like that; java generics are invariant. Instead of writing `new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()`, you should have written `new ArrayList<List<String>>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem. It would have other problems if you do this.

Consider this code:

```
List<List<String>> myList  = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
myList.push( new LinkedList<String>() );   // impossible to catch, because java don't have generic in runtime

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list2 = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) myList; // ok

ArrayList<String> something = list2.get(0);  // doh! impossible to assign LinkedList to ArrayList
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

You need to pass in the type, which can be an interface into the `ArrayList` constructor. In other words you want an `ArrayList` which contains objects of type `List<String>`. Then when you are actually putting things into the list:

```
mList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one should be:

```
List<List<String>> myList  = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

The semantics are the following: the type `myList` is a `List` containg objects of type `List<String>`. The implementation class is an `ArrayList` capable of containing objects of type `List<String>`.

Once you want to add an object to myList you can to it like this:

```
myList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is a little subtle. To make it correct, you'd want:

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

The definition of myList is asking for a **List of Lists of Strings**, but you are implementing it as an **ArrayList of ArrayLists of Strings**, and these don't match. This would becoming an issue if later on you tried something like:

```
myList.add(new LinkedList<String>());
```

This is ok by the definition of **List of Lists of Strings**, but violates the definition of the implementation. LinkedList **is a List**, but **is not** an ArrayList.

If you want to enforce that it is an **ArrayList of ArrayLists of Strings**, then you can use the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList` definition, but it's generally better to keep to interfaces.

With my revised code, you can still make it in the **implementation** an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Strings.

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
{
 myList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

It agrees with the definition of myList as an **List of Lists of Strings**, but you still reap the benefits of using an ArrayList behind the scenes.

Comment: Generics are for specifics.Tomorrow when u pass this list out of your domain, you can get arrayList, LinkedList . code to specifics in generics.

Comment: I don't know if I completely understand. Could you please elaborate :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
`List<? extends List<String>> myList  = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

The reason that your first line does not work is that you cannot do `List<A> = List<B>`, even if `B` is a subtype of `A` (as it is here, ArrayList is a subtype of List). Otherwise it would violate type safety. This is a basic Generics feature that many beginners have trouble with. However, you can do `List<? extends A> = List<B>`; in this case, the `? extends A` is a wildcard that *could include B*. In exchange, you lose the ability to add things to a `List<? extends A>` (Rule: extends producer, super consumer), and this eliminates the safety problem.